# Simple MCMC Bayesian Inference in R

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm looking for a simple MCMC Bayesian network Inference function/package in R. Essentially, I just want a function that accepts the matrix containing my samples x my variables ( + optional parameters like burn-in and iteration counts) and returns the adjacency matrix of the inferred network.

I had been using the Matlab toolkit "BayesNet", which offers a simple 'learn_struct_mcmc' function which offers most of what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an equivalent in R.

I've been looking through the packages in http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Bayesian.html, but haven't seen anything that quite does what I'm looking for. I wasn't trained as a statistician, and many of the packages I've looked at on that list either lack documentation or have more complicated statistics than I'm comfortable wiring together myself. I just need a simple function with "reasonable" defaults to get started.

Bonus points for something that leverages Rmpi or snow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what I had in mind that I've found is the `hc()` function in the  [`blearn` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/index.html). They have a variety of other Bayesian network inference functions, as well, some of which can use snow.

Answer (score 2):

This gave me 132 possible relevant functions.

```
library(sos)
findFn("bayesian network")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I looked through the libraries and wasn't able to find anything that met my needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about this package.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCpack/index.html

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the code I need were in there somewhere, but the manual is 154 pages. Can you be more specific about what function, in particular, you think would be of use?